# How to load in an external CSS file dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a dynamic page using external .css pages where the page color will get changed. Below is my code. But when I click the `href`, I am not getting any output. Can anyone please tell me what's the problem in my code?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
    if (filetype=="css")
    { 
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") 
</script>
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css')">Load "oldstyle.css"</a>
```

I have modified my code as below. Still, I'm facing the problem of getting the output. No result. Can anyone please help me out?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newstyle.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
    if (filetype=="css") 
    {
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
        fileref.type = "text/css";
        fileref.href = "filename";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}
loadjscssfile("oldstyle.css", "css") 
</script>
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css')">Load "oldstyle.css"</a> 
</head>
```

Comment: you could, however, add a few lines to the css, using a different class for the body element. then use jquery/javascript to dynamically change its class. this way you don't need to make another request.

Comment: Note: the <a> tag does *not* belong inside the <head> tag.

Comment: This can be used: http://asimishaq.com/dynamically-loading-css-and-js-files

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
fileref.type = "text/css";
fileref.href = filename;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you . . . is your browser reporting any javascript errors?  Can you confirm that the function is being called, and that it's getting to the line that would append the link (such as by sticking an alert in there and seeing if it gets called)? Also, what browser are you using, and what version?

If you can answer these questions I'll try to help more.

Comment: And 12 years later, someone fixed the error in this answer. :)

Answer (score 15):

Tim Goodman's answer is correct, but instead of `fileref.href = "filename";` it should be `fileref.href = filename;`

Otherwise you're trying to load a file with the name "filename" rather than what you passed to the script.

Alternately, if you're willing to use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library, this can be accomplished in one line:
`$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' id='extracss' href='"+filename+"' type='text/css' />");`

Also, about the first version of your script using setAttribute: Most browsers will only take setAttribute with an empty third parameter because of the way the spec is set up:
`fileref.setAttribute("href", filename, "");`

Comment: Someone just corrected my answer to remove the quotes.  So there you go, only 12 years  late.  Sorry I didn't see this one at the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a style line in your html and just using @import in the css to get the new file

Answer (score 0):

That code should work, except perhaps you might want to add type="text/javascript" to your script tag.

I tested the code via Firebug and it worked for me.

Maybe the problem is that your original stylesheet is still included in the page and thus overriding the style of your secondary stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```

it might work, your code may working but due to some another css it won't reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css')">Load "oldstyle.css"</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css');">Load "oldstyle.css"</a>
```

I belive the onclick, event to href will reload the new file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have an anchor element in the `<head>` section. Secondly, are you sure your CSS path is correct? I'm asking because you already have a reference to `css/newstyle.css` but your are trying to load `newstyle.css`. Are you sure it's not `css/newstyle.css`?

**Edit:** [Here](http://jsbin.com/evada/edit) is a working example of your own code. There is something else wrong. Try to statically link the CSS and see if you are getting the styles. If not, there may be errors in your stylesheet.

By statically linking the stylesheet, I meant to say add this in your page instead of loading from javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/oldstyle.css" />
```

Comment: hi, i have changed it from newstyle.css to css/newstyle.css but still its nt working

Comment: Well, is the file present in the folder?

Comment: ya its in the same folder path is correctly specified thats sure

Comment: Is it working if you statically link it via a link tag? Are you sure there are no errors in the stylesheet?

Comment: ya i have tried that also when i click the link its just remains same color without any change .. even its not showing any errors also..

Answer (score -1):

I did not like the idea of adding additional links to the document, as it leads to a memory leak.

Instead, I tried something else.

In the document's head:

```
<head>
<link id="changeme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/oldstyle.css" />
<!-- moar stuff hear -->
</head>
```

In JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function loadFile(filename) {
  const link = document.querySelector("#changeme");
  link.href = filename;
}
const sheets = ["/css/theme1.css", "/css/theme2.css", "/css/theme3.css"];
let pos = 0;
let timer = setInterval(()=>{
  loadFile(sheets[pos]);
  pos = pos + 1;
  if (pos >= sheets.length) {
    pos = 0;
  }
}, 2000);
</script>
```

This simply replaces the href already in your head, easily identified using a handy id.  In this sample, every two seconds it moves from theme1 to theme2, to theme3, back to theme1 again, until someone leaves the page.  Great for indecisive websites.

(I have no idea how portable this is, so caveat emptor... but it works on Firefox and Chromium, which was good enough for my needs).

Answer (score -7):

' document.createElement("link") ' creates hyper link object, not css style tag() element,  so you are not able to apply this dynamically

correct me if i am wrong

Comment: That is incorrect. It's a <link> element, which is exactly what he wants to load in an external stylesheet.