# Dynamically loading an external CSS file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically loading an external CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099517/dynamically-loading-an-external-css-file)

I'm trying to create a dynamic page using external .css pages where the page color will get changed. Below is my code. But when I click the `href`, I am not getting any output. Can anyone please tell what's the problem in my code? Any suggestions or ideas please.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
    if (filetype=="css")
    { 
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") 
</script>
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css')">Load "oldstyle.css"</a>
```

I have modified my code as below. Still I'm facing the problem in getting output. No result. Can anyone please help me out?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/newstyle.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
    if (filetype=="css") 
    {
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
        fileref.type = "text/css";
        fileref.href = "filename";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}
loadjscssfile("oldstyle.css", "css") 
</script>
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('oldstyle.css','css')">Load "oldstyle.css"</a> 
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch a style of site on some instance (click), without refreshing page, then you need to use JS and cookies both.

May be below link will helpful:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use jquery for this.

Found this great [article on how it can be done](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2006/05/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery/):

Happy coding