# access component from .js file vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loading-overlay

My `main.js` file looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

And App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <loading
        :active.sync= "isLoading" 
        :can-cancel= "false" 
        :is-full-page= "false">
    </loading>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
//import Vue from 'vue';
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

//Vue.use(Loading);

export default {
    data() {
            return {
                isLoading: true
            }
        },
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Loading
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

This seems to work fine, but how can I manipulate the `isLoading` to be true or false, from `main.js`? I might be building a function or something in main.js for future use, and instead of having the `<loading>` on each view page, I would prefer to be able to control it globally some how.

Comment: Maybe you can pass an `isLoading` prop to App.vue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757116

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but based on the referenced answer in my comment, this might work:

main.js

```
new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    props: ['isLoading'], 
    components:{App}, 
    template: '<App v-bind:isLoading="true">' 
})
```

You would have to make `isLoading` a prop in App.vue. The v-bind part above should make the prop reactive.

Also, you could create a bus and send events from main.js to App.vue, then update isLoading accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use store for it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isLoader: false,
    },
    getters: {
        isLoader(state) {
            return state.isLoader
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        isLoader(state, status) {
            state.isLoader = status
        },
    },
    actions: {
        isLoader({commit}, status) {
            commit('isLoader', status)
        },
    }
})
```

everywhere in your application you can set the isLoader to true using `dispatch`

```
vue.$store.dispatch("isLoader", true/false);
```

Comment: Unless Vuex is used through the whole application, it could become cumbersome to just use it only for this.

Comment: what about using a prototype variable to determine true/false ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but for this incident, I believe he will want to render the loader from different component. I think it's popular to manage loader from store. Correct me if I'm not right.

Comment: Adding property to manage true/false, can be a good idea, just for app component. but  if you want to render loader from other routes in your application, that as no relationship to app component. you'il be in trouble.