# Passing props to Vue root instance via attributes on element the app is mounted on

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am terribly new to Vue, so forgive me if my terminology is off.  I have a .NET Core MVC project with small, separate vue pages.  On my current page, I return a view from the controller that just has:

```typescript
@model long;

<div id="faq-category" v-bind:faqCategoryId="@Model"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/scripts/js/faqCategory.js"></script>
}
```

Where I send in the id of the item this page will go grab and create the edit form for.  `faqCategory.js` is the compiled vue app.  I need to pass in the `long` parameter to the vue app on initialization, so it can go fetch the full object.  I mount it with a `main.ts` like:

```typescript
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import FaqCategoryPage from './FaqCategoryPage.vue'

createApp(FaqCategoryPage)
    .mount('#faq-category');
```

How can I get my `faqCategoryId` into my vue app to kick off the initialization and load the object?  My `v-bind` attempt seems to not work - I have a `@Prop(Number) readonly faqCategoryId: number = 0;` on the vue component, but it is always `0`.

My FaqCategoryPAge.vue script is simply:

```html
<script lang="ts">

    import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
    import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import Card from "@/Card.vue";
    import axios from "axios";
    import FaqCategory from "../shared/FaqCategory";
    
    @Options({
        components: {
            Card,
        },
    })
    export default class FaqCategoryPage extends Vue {
        @Prop(Number) readonly faqCategoryId: number = 0;
    
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.faqCategoryId);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It seems passing props to root instance vie attributes placed on element the app is mounting on [is not supported](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6440)

You can solve it using `data-` attributes easily

Vue 2

```js
const mountEl = document.querySelector("#app");

new Vue({
  propsData: { ...mountEl.dataset },
  props: ["message"]
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-message="Hello from HTML">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Vue 3

```js
const mountEl = document.querySelector("#app");

Vue.createApp({  
  props: ["message"]
}, { ...mountEl.dataset }).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.0/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-message="Hello from HTML">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Biggest disadvantage of this is that everything taken from `data-` attributes is a string so if your component expects something else (`Number`, `Boolean` etc) you need to make conversion yourself.

One more option of course is pushing your component one level down. As long as you use `v-bind` (`:counter`), proper JS type is passed into the component:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    MyComponent: {
      props: {
        message: String,
        counter: Number
      },
      template: '<div> {{ message }} (counter: {{ counter }}) </div>'
    }
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.0/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component :message="'Hello from HTML'" :counter="10" />
</div>
```

### Just an idea (not a real problem)

Not really sure but it can be a problem with [Props casing](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-casing-camelcase-vs-kebab-case)

*HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you're using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents*

Try to change your MVC view into this:

```html
<div id="faq-category" v-bind:faq-category-id="@Model"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but it seems to have no effect.  I event tried changing the property to `id` to bypass any of these issues, but it still comes through as `0`

Comment: You might find the following also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50757116/5113030 (*...render: h => h(App, {props:{ source:' source prop'}})*...)

Answer (score 15):

Further to [Michal Levý's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64010905/3251627) answer regarding **Vue 3**, you can also implement that pattern with a Single File Component:

**app.html**

```
<div id="app" data-message="My Message"/>
```

**app.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './my-component.vue';
const mountEl = document.querySelector("#app");

Vue.createApp(MyComponent, { ...mountEl.dataset }).mount("#app");
```

**my-component.vue**

```
<template>
  {{ message }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    message: String
  }
};
</script>
```

---

Or you could even grab data from anywhere on the parent HTML page, eg:

**app.html**

```
<h1>My Message</h1>
<div id="app"/>
```

**app.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import MyComponent from './my-component.vue';
const message = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;

Vue.createApp(MyComponent, { message }).mount("#app");
```

**my-component.vue**

```
<template>
  {{ message }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    message: String
  }
};
</script>
```

---

To answer [TheStoryCoder's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404541/thestorycoder) question: you would need to use a data prop. My answers above demonstrate how to pass a value from the parent DOM to the Vue app when it is mounted. If you wanted to then change the value of `message` after it was mounted, you would need to do something like this (I've called the data prop `myMessage` for clarity, but you could also just use the same prop name `message`):

```
<template>
  {{ myMessage }}
  <button @click="myMessage = 'foo'">Foo me</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    message: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myMessage: this.message
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: How can I then later update the message variable so that the component will use that new value?

Comment: perfect answer for me

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not at all familiar with .NET and what model does, but Vue will treat the DOM element as a placeholder only and it does not extend to it the same functionality as the components within the app have.

so `v-bind` is not going to work, even without the value being reactive, the option is not there to do it.

you could try a hack to access the value and assign to a data such as...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data(){
        return {
        faqCategoryId: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const props = ["faqCategoryId"]
    const el = this.$el.parentElement;
    props.forEach((key) => {
      const val = el.getAttribute(key);
      if(val !== null) this[key] = (val);
    })
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" faqCategoryId="12">
  <h1>Faq Category Id: {{faqCategoryId}}</h1>
</div>
```

where you get the value from the html dom element, and assign to a `data`. The reason I'm suggesting data instead of props is that props are setup to be write only, so you wouldn't be able to override them, so instead I've used a variable `props` to define the props to look for in the dom element.

---

#### Another option

is to use [`inject/provide`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#provide)

it's easier to just use js to provide the variable, but assuming you want to use this in an mvc framework, so that it is managed through the view only. In addition, you can make it simpler by picking the exact attributes you want to pass to the application, but this provides a better "framework" for reuse.

```js
const mount = ($el) => {
  const app = Vue.createApp({
    inject: {
      faqCategoryId: {
        default: 'optional'
      },
    },
  })

  const el = document.querySelector($el)

  Object.keys(app._component.inject).forEach(key => {
    if (el.getAttribute(key) !== null) {
      app.provide(key, el.getAttribute(key))
    }
  })

  app.mount('#app')
}

mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" faqCategoryId="66">
  <h1>Faq Category Id: {{faqCategoryId}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i tried in the following example

```
https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/vYGvXvq
```

you could do :

```
mounted() {
 console.log(this.$el.parentElement.getAttribute("faqCategoryId"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All other answers might be valid, but for Vue 3 the simple way is here:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue'

import rootComponent from './app.vue'

let rootProps = {};

createApp(rootComponent, rootProps)
   .mount('#somewhere')
```

Comment: Why does this have negative votes?, it works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

In the loaded component u can use the same props and in the beforeMount() function set the following:

```js
this.$root.$props.{prop_name} = this.{prop_name}
```

i.e.:

```js
props: [
    'data'
],
beforeMount() {
    this.$root.$props.data = this.data;
}
```