# How to pass JSON variable to Vue App + Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple index.html file. It includes the Vue JS application and has the following code.

**index.html**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script>
            const foo = {
                bar: 100
            };
        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here's how the Vue JS app looks like.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "./App.vue"

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app")
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ config.bar }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        config: {
            type: Object,
            default: () => {},
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I simply want to pass the `const foo` variable into the App.vue file. I already tried to pass it as a prop to the `<div id="app" :config="foo"></div>`, however it did throw an undefined error in App.vue.

How can I pass a JS variable from HTML into a Vue Application and to the component?

Comment: You don't need to pass it, you can just access `foo` anywhere in your code.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64460238/8172857