# How to provide props to a root component in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue2 it was possible to do a pattern like so:

```js
import TopLevelComponent from './TopLevelComponent.vue';

// const someLocalConfig = { prop1: 'val1', ... };

const app = new Vue({
  data() { return {}; },
  render: h => h(TopLevelComponent, {props: someLocalConfig})
});
```

Which gave you a way to use a single file component for the root component while booting the app by injecting config from elsewhere.

How do I do this in Vue3?

I've [read](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance) that I can do this:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import TopLevelComponent from './TopLevelComponent.vue';

const app = createApp(TopLevelComponent);
```

But how can I pass in `someLocalConfig` as the *props* for the app/top level component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing props to Vue root instance via attributes on element the app is mounted on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010560/passing-props-to-vue-root-instance-via-attributes-on-element-the-app-is-mounted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a 2nd object parameter to `createApp` - this replaces the old way of doing a very similar thing (`propsData`)

Here is an example from the [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/props-data.html#_3-x-update):

```
const app = createApp(
  {
    props: ['username'],
    template: '<div>{{ username }}</div>'
  },
  { username: 'Evan' }
)
```

In your case specifically:

```
const app = createApp(TopLevelComponent, someLocalConfig);
```

Comment: But how do you modify the props?