How to get in Vue view parameters from express sendFile() method
I am building a Node app that uses Express, Vue and ThreeJS. I have this setup for express in the backend:
const app = express();

app.post('*', (req, res) => {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'url': req.body.url
        }
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'), options);
});

The file "index.html" contains:
<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>

And "main.js" is where the Vue main view is mounted.
Now, the URL that is contained in "options" refers to a 3D mesh file that will be loaded by ThreeJS in the Vue view (frontend). So what I need to know is how to get that "options" inside the Vue view to get the URL from it. Is there a way to read the headers from a Vue view?
And if there is another approach to get to do this, I would like to know it. I am quite lost regarding Node in general.
I was thinking on using a template instead of "index.html" and create an html element with value={ url }, so I could read the DOM with the Vue app somehow, but it sounds quite goofy. I haven't tried it though, there has to be a better way.

It's not as goofy as it may seem, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010560/passing-props-to-vue-root-instance-via-attributes-on-element-the-app-is-mounted . You can pass data through global vars in the template. A more reasonable approach for SPA is to have rest endpoint to fetch data from

Can't you use URL params or query params? Btw, why do you even use Node for here, looks complicated for no reason. Isn't Nuxt able to solve any SSR needs?

Thank you for the comments. I have so little experience with web apps out of Python, so I am probably not using the best approach. I'll try your answers and publish an answer once I manage to do it. Also, I'll check Nuxt, I have never used it but might find an answer with it.

I managed to get it done with templates (using Pug). In the template, I imported the JS module as follows:
script(type="module", src="src/main.js", data-json={"url":url}, id="module-script")

Then, in the JS module, I got the variable with:
const url = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("module-script").dataset.json).url;

Also, I am not using Vue anymore because raw JS is good enough for this project.
